# Research Gate does not count my citations

Tags: social-media

I have a question related to Reasearch Gate and citation count.

My co-authors have uploaded some conference papers in which I was author too. I decide to create a profile in RG and when I do I realize that the citations from those papers do not added in my profile. In Stats section in RG i can see the Reads but the Citations is -- (i.e. 0).

Does anyone know the reason and if it is possible to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author who uploaded the article on researchgate can invite the co-authors. According to my experience the citation and other states usually takes 7 to 10 days to appear in co-author profile.